# Trying to run a batch file that opens MATLAB with PSEXEC

Tags: matlab, batch-file, cmd, psexec

I am trying to run a batch file in computer 1, which contains a PSEXEC command to launch another batch file in computer 2 which runs a MATLAB script.

When I run the parent batch file it launches the command prompt and I get as an output the path I provided for to the children batch file to open the MATLAB script but MATLAB never launches. Also when I manually run the children batch file in computer 2 it does launch MATLAB normally.

Any ideas why this is happening?

I have tried different PSEXEC commands such as

```
psexec -h \\IPadress -u userName -p myPassword cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\user\Desktop\matlab.bat"

psexec -h -i \\IPadress -u userName -p myPassword cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\user\Desktop\matlab.bat"

psexec -h -i -s \\IPadress -u userName -p myPassword cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\user\Desktop\matlab.bat"
```

but nothing has worked so far. Additionally, to make sure this is an isolated issue I have run another batch file with a simple command to create a text file and it does work normally, here is the batch file text.

```
 psexec -h \\IPadress -u userName -p myPassword cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test.bat"
```

which runs this batch file

```
@echo on
echo Woohoo! > %~dp0test.txt
```

which tells me this has to do with either MATLAB or the type of command I am using. Lastly, yes, IP address, username and password I am putting in the actual command are correct.

```
psexec -h \\IPadress -u userName -p myPassword cmd.exe /c "C:\Users\user\Desktop\matlab.bat"
```

Comment: Does the simple command that works, just run something that doesn't require a desktop interface?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to show exactly what options you've tried (full command line, not just a passing mention of them).

Comment: And why would a MatLab application need to run elevated?

Comment: @jwdonahue correct it just creates a text file in the same directory as the children batch file. I did this to make sure PSEXEC does work, which indeed it does. I have modified the post with more information including the simple test batch file I ran to make sure it works. I assumed elevated token means admin privileges and that's why I included this command.

Comment: Never run a process elevated unless you really have to.  In this case, I don't think you do.  The `-i` option will default to running in the console session on the target machine. Is your user logged onto the console of the target machine?

Comment: @jwdonahue thanks for the clarification on elevated token. Also, I don't think it is logged onto the console on the target machine. As far as I know I need to have RDC settings to do that which I have not done. Please let me know if I'm correct or if there is something different I need to do in order to see if I have logged onto the console machine.